# Monitoring a specific application for creation or modification of files

Tags: operating-systems, file-system, monitoring

I don't know if I'm looking for a file integrity monitoring software here.

Basically let's say we have firefox or chromium, let's say the user is watching a youtube video, then we'll find that video in our cache right? Now i would like to know if a specific application is creating or modifying some file, even if it calls an "external module" (like, I don't know, launching `mkdir` command on linux from our target application).

I need a software that does that online, when it's happening. I have just to tell him which process has to be monitored.

I need it for Windows right now but since the application is multi-platform a Linux solution would be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for something interactive, and not service-style long-term monitoring software, check out Microsoft's (nee SysInternal) [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).
Very versatile.

Answer (score 7):

On the Linux side you can do this kind of monitoring using the [auditd](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) subsystem and very cleverly written rules. It can be used to watch for changes to files or directories, entry or exits of system calls, etc.